# What is wrong with dividing the calculated fields total and count below

Tags: mongodb

I am not getting NULL. What could i be missing?

Suggesting with using below division:

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            borough: [
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: {borough: "$borough"},
                        total: {$sum: 1}
                    }
                }
            ],
            cuisine: [
                {
                    $match: {"cuisine": "American "}
                },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: {borough: "$borough"},
                        count: {$sum: 1}
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            workdays: {$divide: ["$total", "$count"]}
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: These `borough` & `cuisine` are arrays you need to get elements out of array & do divide(Also if each group have multiple array then how do you want to divide ? Total/count of which object to which object) , Can you give us sample docs prior to this last `$project` stage..

Comment: {
  "address": {
     "building": "1007",
     "coord": [ -73.856077, 40.848447 ],
     "street": "Morris Park Ave",
     "zipcode": "10462"
  },
  "borough": "Bronx",
  "cuisine": "Bakery",
  "grades": [
     { "date": { "$date": 1393804800000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 2 },
  ],
  "name": "Morris Park Bake Shop",
  "restaurant_id": "30075445"
}

Comment: such type of data for 30k value

Comment: Check this : https://mongoplayground.net/p/_mZ_utHZ0Hm , You would an array of objects !! How would you wanna divide, do you wanna divide "jersey Total/ jersey count"  or "sum of all Total/ sum of all counts" ??

Comment: No I what i want is to group by the boroughs and count that, then i want to divide the count of borough as per a cuisine type say bakery by group by the boroughs and the count received. I used facet to get these two array so that i can try and divide  this and then sort it to get the smallest ratio

Comment: is there a better way to do it?

Comment: can you please give us required output from that point..!!!!!

Comment: yes i want  "jersey Total/ jersey count" and similary for bronx total/bronx count

Comment: Check the data in link & test it :: https://mongoplayground.net/p/PGkWHwViqPm , I guess this is what you're looking for, let me know on it I would put it as an answer..

Comment: Please [edit] the question to contain proper information. Now it's totally unclear and there's important parts in comments instead.

Comment: Please edit your question and add sample documents there instead of putting them into comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close but you need to change your `$project` a little:

```
{
    $project: {
        workdays: {$divide: ["$borough.0.total", "$cuisine.0.count"]}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks So much I got my answer using this!